# Terminal - Give credentials in terminal without GUI

Tags: bash, terminal, git, cinnamon

I'm on Arch Linux, Cinnamon Desktop environment, having Bash as my default shell.

Recently, when I commit changes on Git, Bash prompts a window asking for credentials while a few days ago no GUI windows would appear and Git used to ask for credentials on Bash itself.

I'm not sure if this credentials prompt window is related to Git itself or my desktop environment, but I don't want Git to launch a window for asking credentials. I want to give credentials assuming no GUI desktop is available.
Is it possible that some packages were accidentally installed alongside others and changed this?

Comment: Is Cinnamon Gnome-based? perhaps the `gnome-keyring` has taken over management of your SSH keys? See for example [GNOME/Keyring](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring)

Comment: @steeldriver I'm not sure if Cinnamon is Gnome-based but I guess it is because I haven't installed gnome but it did install alongside Cinnamon and now I have two desktops, but only working with Cinnamon. Anyway, gnome-keyring is not installed though so I'm pretty sure it doesn't have anything to do with this, even if it was installed, it manages passwords and the link led me to git credentials.helper and not the asking password part. Thanks for sharing anyway, the link made things more clear for next search.

Comment: @steeldriver Okay this is so weird but unsetting DISPLAY variable (unset DISPLAY) just did the magic! I also exported the GPG_TTY=$(tty) variable in my .bashrc and I'm not sure if it's involved, but the thing is, gpg looks for DISPLAY global variable and uses pinentry-curses (?) if no DISPLAY was available. That's it. I'm going to unset DISPLAY in .bashrc in the hope of not messing anything else up. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55126554/5536921

Comment: Answer: https://superuser.com/a/521027/705273 in fact I didn't know it was all about gpg but that's it. here's the answer. gpg should be forced to use /usr/bin/pinentry-tty by configuring it in ~/.gnugp/gpg-agent.conf